# How can I keep from returning white spaces and line returns in-between nodes with xpath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to learn to use Java xpath, but have run into an issue. When I use getNodeName and getTextContent, I end up grabbing the whitespace and line returns that occur in-between nodes. For example, if my XML looks like:

```
<node-i-am-looking-for-in-my-xml>
    <parent-node-01>
        <child-node-01>
            some text
        </child-node>
        <child-node-02>
            some more text
        </child-node>
        <child-node-03>
            even more text
        </child-node>
    </parent-node-01>
    <parent-node-02>
        <child-node-01>
            some text
        </child-node>
        <child-node-02>
            some more text
        </child-node>
        <child-node-03>
            even more text
        </child-node>
    </parent-node-02>
    <parent-node-03>
        <child-node-01>
            some text
        </child-node>
        <child-node-02>
            some more text
        </child-node>
        <child-node-03>
            even more text
        </child-node>
    </parent-node-03>
</node-i-am-looking-for-in-my-xml>
```

What I get when I use getNodeName looks like:

```
child-node-01
#text
child-node-02
#text
child-node-03
#text
```

And when I use getTextContent, it looks like:

```
some text

some more text

even more text
```

This is the code I am using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    String filename = "C:\\Users\\Me\\file.xml";
    Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File(filename)));
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    String expression;
    Node node;
    NodeList nodeList;

    expression = "//node-i-am-looking-for/*";
    nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    System.out.println("nodeList.getLength(): " + nodeList.getLength());
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<(nodeList.item(i).getChildNodes().getLength()); j++){
            Node nowNode = nodeList.item(i).getChildNodes().item(j);
            System.out.println(nowNode.getNodeName() + ":" + nowNode.getTextContent());
        }
    }
}
```

In looking around Google, it appears I need to use "normalize-space", but I cannot figure out how to implement that.

Comment: Quick workaround for this specific problem: use System.out.print instead of println so no extra linebreak is appended.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but that won't work for my situation. The code I pasted is just an example of what I am doing. I need a more "durable" solution.

Comment: Then you'll probably want to have a look at this answer which shows ways of handling whitespace and linebreaks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007527/xpath-to-get-all-text-in-element-as-one-value-removing-line-breaks

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But, like I said, I cannot figure out how to implement it. I'm not sure where to use the "normalize-space()" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen, whitespace is significant in XML text nodes.  The text contents of `child-node-01` (or more accurately, the contents of the text node whose parent is `child-node-01`) is actually `'\n       some text\n       '`.

You would only use `normalize-space` if you needed to deal with this whitespace inside an XPath expression, as `normalize-space` is an XPath function.  For example, if you wanted to select all nodes where the text contents (with leading/trailing whitespace stripped) was `'some data'`, you could have an XPath like:

```
//*[normalize-space(.) = 'some data']
```

But by the time you've retrieved the text content, you're outside of the XPath world, and back in Java, so you might be better off with:

```
nowNode.getTextContent().trim()
```

Comment: Thank you, that works for the getTextContent, but what about the "#text" node that is being generated, that shows up in my output?

Comment: Well, those text nodes are real.  There is actually a text node, for example, in between `child-node-01` and `child-node-02`, containing the newlines and spaces that were used for formatting.  You have to take them into account when you use `getChildNodes()` and skip them.  You can avoid this by being more specific with your XPath, and only select the nodes you want to deal with.  Maybe something along the lines of `//*[starts-with(name(), 'child-node')]`.  If you loop on that nodeset, you will only get element nodes, and can grab the text content of each.